# Maya Python: Custom Window - modelEditor ignores flags

Tags: python, user-interface, layout, maya

.Hi everyone,

I`m still pretty new to python so, bear with me.

I am trying to setup a custom UI Window in maya, with a custom camera.
For this i am using the `panelLayout`, `modelPanel` and `modelEditor` commands.

Now, it's working so far with one exception. 
The flags i've set for the modelEditor seem to be ignored entirely and i dont know why.

So here is the code:

```
if cmds.window("myWindow", exists=True):
    cmds.deleteUI('myWindow')

cmds.window("myWindow")
cmds.paneLayout(configuration="single", w=1000, h=500)
cmds.modelPanel()
cmds.modelEditor(modelPanel="modelPanel4", allObjects=False, polymeshes=True, imagePlane=True, displayAppearance="smoothShaded")

cmds.showWindow("myWindow")
```

I want only polyMeshes and imgagePlanes to show in this window, aswell as to have the `displayAppearance` set to "smoothShaded". 
Nnothing else, including the grid, should be visible at this point. 
but, everything show up in the window, as if i had'nt set a single flag.

any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

All the flags in `modelEditor()` work fine in Maya 2016.5 and Maya 2018. I've checked it.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

if cmds.window("myWindow", exists=True):
    cmds.deleteUI('myWindow')

cmds.window("myWindow")
cmds.paneLayout(configuration="single", w=1000, h=500)
cmds.modelPanel()
cmds.modelEditor(modelPanel="modelPanel4",
                 allObjects=False, 
                 polymeshes=True, 
                 imagePlane=False, 
                 displayAppearance="smoothShaded")

cmds.showWindow("myWindow")
```

The problem might appear when you click `myWindow` or press any key. It'll show not perspective view (`modelPanel4`) but the other view (for instance `camera1` view).

Comment: thanks. In maya 2017 it doesnt work tho, and due to pipline i have to stick to it for now. I´m not quite sure what you mean by " click myWindow" tho.

EDIT // just tested. in maya 18 this code doesnt work!

Comment: I have maya 18 open right now with a fresh scene, all i did was run this script but it doesnt work, at least for me! Oh, and the new window is not supposed to show the default perspective view, its supposed to show a created camera in the scene. my bad